# Popular posts reset count (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a website owner and a beginner web developer, my knowledge so far sums in HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
However, for my website daily use I have found and implemented the following PHP code:

```
// Popular Posts
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
        $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }
    }
    //To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);

function wpb_track_post_views ($post_id) {
    if ( !is_single() ) return;
    if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;    
    }
    wpb_set_post_views($post_id);
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_track_post_views');
```

It works pretty great, however I want to make the count reset automatically every week, and start counting from zero again.

Can someone please help me achieve that? (unfortunately google couldn't help with this one...)

P.S. I don't want to use a plugin!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';


    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }

    $timeStamp_key = 'wpb_post_views_timestemp';

    $lastDate = date('d',strtotime("",get_post_meta($postID,$timeStamp_key,true)));
    $currentDate = date("d",strtotime('-7 Days',time()));

    if($lastDate == $currentDate) {
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        update_post_meta($postID,$timeStamp_key,date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }
}
```

**Try this working or not.**

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work... ( I even changed the time to 1 minute yet nothing happened)

Comment: When you saving or updating your post add save_post hook there and add this update_post_meta(POST OF THAT ID,'wpb_post_views_timestemp',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));